# How to toggle off bootstrap offcanvas when clicking link inside

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a One page proyect and I have a navbar inside an offcanvas component in Bootstrap 5.1.3. What I need is when I click on a link (.nav-link) on the menu, the offcanvas toggles off automatically.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
            <div class="offcanvas-header">
                <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="offcanvas-body">
                <div class="text-center mb-5">
                    <a href="index.php" title="HEREDERO GIN" class="d-block position-relative"><img src="global/img/logo-naranja.svg" alt="HEREDERO GIN" class="logo-naranja" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-column w-100 text-center navbar-offcanvas">

                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/" title="ORIGEN"><span>ORIGEN</span> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#producto" title="PRODUCTO"><span>PRODUCTO</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#momentos" title="MOMENTOS"><span>MOMENTOS</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#herederoOpen" title="HEREDERO OPEN"><span>HEREDERO OPEN</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#tienda" title="TIENDA"><span>TIENDA</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link " href="#contacto" title="CONTACTO"><span>CONTACTO</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="ig-dire text-center my-3">
                        <a href="#" class="d-block fs-20 text-primary font-family-extra mx-auto mb-0 lh-sm"><small>SEGUINOS EN INSTAGRAM</small> <br><i class="fab fa-instagram me-1" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong>HEREDEROGIN</strong></a>
                    </div>
                    <nav class="nav nav-idioma d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <a href="/" class="nav-link active" title="ESPAÑOL">ESPAÑOL</a>
                        <a href="/" class="nav-link" title="ENGLISH">ENGLISH</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: you want to use the collapse plugin to trigger hidden content elsewhere on the page. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#toggler

Answer (score 2):

this code work for me

```
jQuery("#offcanvas .nav-link").click(function(){
    jQuery('#offcanvas').offcanvas('hide');
});
```

EDIT: This solution does not work very well with anchor links

Answer (score 0):

I have better solution with timeout trigger on button with *data-bs-toggle*

[Bootstrap 5 - Offcanvas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="bs_button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvas" aria-controls="offcanvas">Toggle top offcanvas</button>

        
$('#offcanvas .nav-link').on('click', function() {    
            $('#offcanvas').removeClass('show');
            $('#top').css('overflow', ''); // <body>
            $('#top').css('padding', '');  // <body>
            $('#offcanvas').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $("#offcanvas").removeAttr('role');
            $("#offcanvas").removeAttr('aria-modal');
            
            setTimeout(function () {
               $("#bs_button").trigger("click");
            }, 800);
});
```